# Angular2 Typescript2: changes to Class property not reflected in DOM objects

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I am trying to dynamically add an object to the DOM, but can't seem to get any changes I make to the class properties to show up in the DOM. Plus I can't seem to change the class name on a DOM object.

When I click I log to the console that the "clicked" method is called, but the style.top and style.left don't change. And neither does the class attribute. I just see this:

```
<div ng-reflect-class-name="marker" class="marker">...</div>
```

Code that's doing the insert:

**page.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

import { Marker } from './marker';

@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
  clicked(e: MouseEvent) {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Marker);
    let component = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 1, this.vcRef.injector);
    component.instance.place(0,0, 50, 0, 150);
  }
}
```

Here's the object I'm trying to add dynamically:

**marker.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '.markers',
    templateUrl: 'marker.html'
})
export class Marker {
  protected left: number;
  protected bottom: number;
  protected class: string;
  protected form: any;

  constructor() {
      this.class = "marker";
      this.form = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        title: ''
    }
  }

  place(percentX: number, percentY: number, x: number, y: number, width: number) {
    console.log("placing");
    this.form.x = percentX;
    this.form.y = percentY;
    this.left = x;
    this.bottom = y;
    if (x < width / 2) {
      this.class = "marker right";
    } else {
      this.class = "marker left";
    }
  }
}
```

**marker.html**

```
<div [class]="class" [style.left]="left" [style.bottom]="bottom">
    <ion-input class="input-title" type="text" placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="form.title"></ion-input>
</div>
```

Any hints for this Angular2 n00b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the "Renderer" and "ElementRef" objects to do the style and class manipulation. I don't think it's the *right* way to use TypeScript - it seems like working around some things - but it's how I got it to work...

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "marker",
    templateUrl: 'marker.html'
})
export class PainStatusMarker {
  protected form: any;

  constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
      this.form = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        title: ''
    }
  }

  place(percentX: number, percentY: number, x: number, y: number, width: number) {
    this.form.x = percentX;
    this.form.y = percentY;
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "bottom", (-1 * y) + 'px');
    if (x < width / 2) {
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement, "right", true);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps others who are new to Angular2 and Typescript